# Convergence of a real-parameterized almost-geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need help with a specific exercise which involves a series with a real value parameter (x) and a similarity with the geometric series. The objective is clearly to tell for which values of x the series converges.

$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-xn^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} [(\frac{1}{e})^x]^{n^2}$

How do you approach a case like this? I tried with the root test but I get stuck with the limit calculus:

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{[(\frac{1}{e})^x]^{n^2}} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} [(\frac{1}{e})^x]^n =$ ?

If the root test was the right way, I suppose my problem translates to a limit calculus.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x>0$, then $e^x>1$, hence $0 < e^{-x}< 1$, thus  $\lim_{n \to +\infty} [(\frac{1}{e})^x]^n =0$.

If $x < 0$, then $e^x < 1$, hence $e^{-x} >1$, thus  $\lim_{n \to +\infty} [(\frac{1}{e})^x]^n = \infty$.

If $x=0$, then $e^{-xn^2}=1$ for all $n$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Limit doubt: what if $x \to +\infty$ and hence $e^{-x} \to 0$ ? You resolve the limit using infinity comparison? In other words, stating that $e^{-x}$ goes to infinity faster than $n^2$ ?

Comment: correction: $e^{-x}$ geos to zero "faster" than $n^2$ goes to infinity